# How do i update marker position without re rendering mapview ? React native maps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I am updating multiple Marker positions based on a marker array state. So when I update it with setState, render function triggers as usual and mapview re renders. Since it has an initial region and region props it automatically focuses on player location based on playerlocation state (I don't want this I only want this on initial load.)

How do I update marker positions without re rendering mapview?

```
 render() {
    return (
      <MapView
        initialRegion={this.state.playerLocation}
        region={this.state.playerLocation}
        style={ styles.map }>
          {this.renderMarkers()}
       </MapView>
    );
  }

renderMarkers = () => {
  return(
    this.state.markers.map(marker=>{
      return(
        <Marker coordinate = {{
           latitude: marker.lat,
           longitude: marker.long
         }}      
         title={marker.id}/>
      )
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common issue in react, and there is a very good solution for it.

Use the lifecycle method called `shouldComponentUpdate`

> https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

You can try to extract render Markers to a separate component and then add the lifeCycle to return False all the time. That was once the component is mounted it will not re-render again.

I'm not sure if this would cause any regressions in your case, but if it does, you can pass a prop which can trigger a re-render in your SCU and update the markers if needed. That is something you would need to play with.