# Is there a way to change react-native-maps <Marker coordinate={coordinate} /> API coordinate without re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

Reference: [How do i update marker position without re rendering mapview ? React native maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52106446/how-do-i-update-marker-position-without-re-rendering-mapview-react-native-maps)

My goal is to prevent re-rendering when user drag the map while also change the market coordinate. The current solution is to use `useState` hook. But it caused the component to re-render, which cause the app to be laggy.

I've tried to use `let variable` but it does not move the `marker`.

`tl:dr` Screen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import MapView, {Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from 'react-native-maps';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});
```

Screen.js with useState (expensive re-rendering)

```
export default function GoSendDestinationDetails() {
  const [coordinate, setCoordinate] = React.useState({
    latitude: -6.1754,
    longitude: 106.8272,
    latitudeDelta: 0.015,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
  });
  const handleRegionChange = (region) => {
    setCoordinate(region);
    console.log(region);
  };

  console.log('re-render');

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={coordinate}
        onRegionChange={handleRegionChange}>
        <MarkerMemo />
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

What I've tried:

Screen.js with let variable

```
export default function GoSendDestinationDetails() {
  let coordinate = {
    latitude: -6.1754,
    longitude: 106.8272,
    latitudeDelta: 0.015,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
  };
  const handleRegionChange = (region) => {
    coordinate = region;
    console.log(region);
  };

  // this does not update the marker when coordinate changes
  const MarkerMemo = React.memo(() => <Marker coordinate={coordinate} />)

  console.log('re-render');
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={coordinate}
        onRegionChange={handleRegionChange}>
        <MarkerMemo />
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`useState` Hook gives you two things:

- a value that will **persist across renders**
- an API to update that value and **trigger a re-render**.

If you had a use case where you don’t care about re-rendering, but you did need to persist a value across renders, you need the half of `useState` that lets you persist a value across renders but not the other half that triggers a re-render.

And that exactly what `useRef` does

> The useRef() Hook isn’t just for DOM refs. The “ref” object is a generic container whose current property is mutable and can hold any value

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables

Answer (score 0):

Get the reference of the marker:

```
const markerRef = useRef();
```

Let's assume you would like to move the marker to the long-pressed point on the map:

```
<MapView
 provider={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? PROVIDER_DEFAULT : PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
 style={styles.map}
 pitchEnabled={false}
 initialRegion={userLocation.current}
 onLongPress={handleUserMarkMap}
 onRegionChange={handleMapDeltaChange}>
 <Marker
   ref={markerRef}
   draggable
   coordinate={markedMapLocation.current}
   onDragEnd={handleUserMarkMap}
  />
 </MapView>
```

You would handle the case as below:

```
const handleUserMarkMap = event => {
 const selectedCoordinate = event?.nativeEvent?.coordinate;
 ....
 // this is the magic function
 markerRef.current.animateMarkerToCoordinate(selectedCoordinate);
};
```

So, this will let you to move your marker without re-rendering the map